# How to create complex dictionary from the text file?

Tags: python

I have text file call this as **testText.txt** which looks like this:

```
#Rooms
room Hall
room Kitchen
room Storage
room Bedroom
room Bathroom
room Garage
#Doors
door N open Hall Bedroom
door N closed Storage Kitchen
door E locked Hall Storage
door E open Bedroom Kitchen
door N open Bedroom Bathroom
door S open Bedroom Hall
door S open Bathroom Bedroom
door W locked Hall Garage
door W open Kitchen Bedroom
door S closed Kitchen Storage
door W open Storage Hall
door E locked Garage Hall
#Items
item car Garage STATIONARY
item remote Kitchen MOVE
item key Bedroom USE
item key Hall USE
#Start position
start Hall
```

and I want to convert the text file into dictionary which looks like this:

```
tempRooms={1:{"name":"Hall","N":{"dir":2,"status":"open"},"E":{"dir":3,"status":"locked"},"W":{"dir":4,"status":"locked"},"item":{"itemName":"key","movementStatus":"USE"},"start":1},
       2:{"name":"Bedroom","E":{"dir":5,"status":"open"},"N":{"dir":6,"status":"open"},"S":{"dir":1,"status":"open"},"item":{"itemName":"key","movementStatus":"USE"},"start":1},
       3:{"name":"Storage","N":{"dir":5,"status":"closed"},"W":{"dir":1,"status":"open"},"start":1},
       4:{"name":"Garage","E":{"dir":1,"status":"locked"},"item":{"itemName":"car","movementStatus":"STATIONARY"},"start":1},
       5:{"name":"Kitchen","W":{"dir":2,"status":"open"},"S":{"dir":3,"status":"closed"},"item":{"itemName":"remote","movementStatus":"MOVE"},"start":1},
       6:{"name":"Bathroom","S":{"dir":2,"status":"open"},"start":1}}
```

I have tried the code but this conversion seems complex to me.What I've tried:dictionary for **ROOMS**

```
with open(filename,'r') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == '#Rooms':  # Or whatever test is needed
            break
    for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
        if line.strip() == '#Doors':
            break
        lines=line.strip().split()
        a=lines[0]
        b=lines[1]
        rooms[a]=b
        print(rooms['room'])
```

Dictionary for **DOORS**

```
with open(filename,'r') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip()=='#Doors':
            break
    for line in input_data:
            if line.strip()=='#Items':
                break
            lines=line.strip().split()
            doors[lines[0]]={'room':lines[3]},{lines[1]:lines[4]},{'status':lines[2]}
            print(doors)
```

But I am not able to get the desired output.I tried various times and different types but failed every time.I have to develop a interactive fiction game(text based adventure game). So, I have data in my text file and I want the exact output of the dictionary.
Where Start Hall is the starting position and Items means where items are present then user will able to pick it up or use it.
Above 1,2,3..etc. denotes the keys.
Please help me to get the desired output.

Comment: What does it mean that 'You failed every time'? What exactly were the attempts, achieved results, and the difference to the desired end result?

Comment: The example shows no more than one item per room (and the output format doesn't appear to support more).  Is that an acceptable limitation?  (The alternative would be to make the output be something like `"items":[{"itemName":"key","movementStatus":"USE"}]` - ie make "items" be a list of dictionaries.)

Comment: Also, can one assume that all rooms are defined before any doors and items?

Comment: You are using a pattern that doesn't work: first reading all from the stream `input_data`, and then trying to read all again, but at that point you are at end-of-file, so the second time will read nothing. I would use another logic, but with what you have, you can reset the stream to the beginning with `input_data.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid unnecessary processing. Loop through each line. Ignore lines starting with # (they don't mean anything). Split each line into words. Look at the first word. If the first word is room, add it to the dictionary. If it's a door or item, add it to the appropriate room(s) in the dictionary.

Comment: I'm unable to do can you help me please

Comment: @User1456 We aren't going to do your homework for you.  Which bit are you having problems with?  "Loop through each line"?  Try and write a program which opens the file, reads each line, and prints it out.  "Ignore lines starting with #"?  Modify the program to not print out lines starting #.  "Split into words"? Modify the program to split each (remaining) line into a list, and then print the list (instead of the line.  .... and so on.

Comment: Once you get stuck, come and ask us about *that specific problem" (once you have checked that the problem isn't already answered here - it probably is).

Comment: Ohk @MartinBonner sir,i'm doing it hope you will help me if i get stuck somewhere